# Less - Change one rule in parametric mixin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm importing bootstrap `mixins.less` and I want to remove the `box-shadow` from the `.form-control-validation` parametric mixin.

I've tried

```
.form-control-validation .form-control { .box-shadow(none); }
```

Is it possible to override just one rule without modifying the original file ?

This is a [reduction](http://jsbin.com/watuwuto/1/edit) of the problem.

I'm trying to avoid making my own clones of BS files so i wont have any problem upgrading in the future. I just need to override specific rules.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly (I assume you want to affect *every* class that uses the `.form-control-validation` mixin) this can be done with:

```
.form-control-validation(...) {
    .form-control {
        .box-shadow(none);
    }
}
```

This mixin should be defined *after* original Bootstrap mixins (i.e. after importing "bootstrap" or "mixins").

Answer (score 0):

I think that defining a rule with default parameter for box-shadow would work. Something like this:

```
.color-border(@col, none) {
  .color-border(@col);
  box-shadow : none;
}

.blue-border { 
  .color-border(blue, none);
}
```

Take a look:
http://jsbin.com/watuwuto/4/edit

Note that I've added a new parameter that will be used only if you call `.color-border(blue, none);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is an interesting tactic but these mixins are used by BS in `forms.less`, not by me. So if i'm trying to avoid cloning files this wont work.